# Dynamic options in Options Framework Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using this plugin options to put my subject, I make a slide of photos, but do not want to set a limit of photos, would be added as needed, any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your safest bet here would be to create a custom post type that feeds the slide of photos as opposed to theme options. The customizor framework as it stands is temperamental and is used more as a user interface for previewing layout and styling changes.

http://www.layerswp.com/ is a theme that allows what you are looking for, but it is not the usual practice as it stands now.

With that being said there are plugins available that might be able to do what you are asking. The best one that I have found is Kirki (http://wptavern.com/kirki-a-free-plugin-to-style-the-wordpress-customizer-and-add-advanced-controls).